# Secret in version "v1" cannot be handled as a Secret: v1.Secret.Data: ReadMapCB: expect { or n, but found ", error found in #10 byte of

Tags: kubernetes

I 'm trying to set up private  docker image registry for kubernetes cluster. I'm following this [link](https://blog.cloudhelix.io/using-a-private-docker-registry-with-kubernetes-f8d5f6b8f646)

```
 $ cat ~/.docker/config.json | base64
  ewoJImF1dGhzIjogewoJCSJsb2NhbGhvc3Q6NTAwMDAiOiB7CgkJCSJhdXRoIjogImJYbDFjMlZ5
  T21oMGNHRnpjM2RrIgoJCX0KCX0KfQ==
```

I have file `image-registry-secrets.yaml` with below contents -

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
 name: registrypullsecret
data:
 .dockerconfigjson:ewoJImF1dGhzIjogewoJCSJsb2NhbGhvc3Q6NTAwMDAiOiB7CgkJCSJhdXRoIjogImJYbDFjMlZ5T21oMGNHRnpjM2RrIgoJCX0KCX0KfQ==
type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
```

And when I run the below command

```
$kubectl create -f image-registry-secrets.yaml --validate=false && kubectl get secrets
Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "image-registry-secrets.yml": Secret in version "v1" cannot be handled as a Secret: v1.Secret.Data: ReadMapCB: expect { or n, but found ", error found in #10 byte of ...|","data":".dockercon|..., bigger context ...|{"apiVersion":"v1","data":".dockerconfigjson:ewoJImF1dGhzIjogewoJCSJsb2NhbGhv|...
```

What is the issue in `kubectl create -f image-registry-secrets.yaml --validate=false` and how can I resolve this error.

Kubernetes version is -

```
$kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"13", GitVersion:"v1.13.0", GitCommit:"ddf47ac13c1a9483ea035a79cd7c10005ff21a6d", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-12-03T21:04:45Z", GoVersion:"go1.11.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"13", GitVersion:"v1.13.4", GitCommit:"c27b913fddd1a6c480c229191a087698aa92f0b1", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-02-28T13:30:26Z", GoVersion:"go1.11.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include a space after `.dockerconfigjson`, and before the base64 string - after that it should work.

Answer (score 0):

When you paste the base64 password, it splits the password between a few lines and adds spaces in between the lines. It is difficult to explain and there is no need to add space after `.dockerconfigjson`, as the yaml provided in the tutorial is correct. The problem occurs after pasting the `base64-encoded-json`.

Open the secret in Vim and run:
`:set listchars+=space:␣` and then `:set list`
this will show all the spaces as `␣`, check if there is none between the password lines. This worked in my case.

Update: 
The Vim command does not always show the spaces, so just navigate to the begging of each line  of your secret key and press backspace so they connect.